# Is there a more efficient solution for this MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql

I am working on extracting and displaying data from a Wordpress DB to a mobile app for a customer and I am having a little trouble refining this query to be most efficient.

In wordpress, there are three tables that link the data I need to access
1. wp_posts - in this table there is the main post title, it's published status and the post type.
2. wp_postmeta - this table has all supplemental info related to the post id in the above table.
3. wp_p2p - this table has links to all the parent-child posts and their relationship.

Because of the volume of data in these tables, the query I currently have takes about 13 seconds to run, could you please take a look at this sqlfiddle and let me know what I could look at to improve it?  The query in it's current form is not the end result, but improving it will improve my end result.  I also need to add a search field on the "name" in the wp_postmeta table.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e9e0/1

Any direction is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: First: the `JOIN` using `!=` is a bad idea.  That's probably most of the problem.  Can you describe what the join with `wp_p2p` is supposed to do?

Comment: how about: `SELECT wp_posts.id,  post_title, post_status, post_type
  FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_p2p
  WHERE `post_status`='publish' AND `post_type`='merchant' 
  AND wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
  AND not exists (select p2p_from FROM wp_p2p WHERE p2p_from=wp_posts.id) 
  GROUP BY wp_posts.id`

Comment: @G-Nugget the wp_p2p join is the table that shows me the parent to child relationship.  Only want to list the children in my results.

Comment: @Panagiotis that shaved of a second or two, it's still taking 12+ seconds on my VPS.

Comment: @OrganizedChaos So am I right in saying that the posts should match with `p2p` entries where the post ID is equal to the `p2p_to`?  I think that's what you mean, but I can't figure out why you'd join them on a `!=`.  It seems like the `JOIN` should use `wp_posts.id = wp_p2p.p2p_to` instead of `wp_posts.id != wp_p2p.p2p_from`.

Comment: Have you indexed the wp_p2p table?

Comment: @Panagiotis The indexes are in the SQL fiddle.

Comment: True, organizedchaos what if you got only the ids and then call the get_post on each of the results?

Comment: @G-Nugget I see where you are coming from.  Not all enteries in the wp_posts table are listed in the wp_p2p table, so what I was ultimately looking to do was make sure that if it's listed as a parent, then I don't want the results returned.  Is that clearer?  I am certain if I match against p2p_to, then there will be missed results.

Comment: @Panagiotis - This query is for a live DB search so I'm actually doing a UNION on it to add a second query and presenting all the results together. I may have to rethink the whole process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for only child posts, in which case, the query below should be much faster:

```
SELECT wp_posts.id,  post_title, post_status, post_type
FROM wp_posts
JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_p2p ON (wp_posts.id = wp_p2p.p2p_from)
WHERE `post_status`='publish' AND `post_type`='merchant' 
AND wp_p2p.p2p_from IS NULL
GROUP BY wp_posts.id
```

This query will be optimized to find where a match doesn't exist in the p2p table so that part will be much faster than how you're currently doing it.  It looks like you can also remove the `JOIN` on `wp_postmeta` since you don't use it at all.  Removing that `JOIN` would also make the `GROUP BY` redundant and removing it could help the performance a little.  Removing the `GROUP BY` would also be a good practice since strictly you can't select non-aggregate fields that aren't in the `GROUP BY` clause, but MySQL provides for this functionality so the query will still work either way.

Comment: This looks like it!  It's down around 0.0023 and it's responding like I'd expect in phpmyadmin.  Thanks for leaving the wp_postmeta stuff in there as it's needed for the rest of what I am doing (search on specific values, not added to the question)  Appreciate the questions and understanding what I needed.  Thank you

Comment: So... based on your comment about removing the GROUP BY, would it be smart to change the wp_posts.id to be DISTINCT() and removing GROUP BY?  I just did a quick test and it seems to be a slight bit faster and the results appear to be the same.

Comment: @OrganizedChaos Is this query only part of a larger query?  using `DISTINCT` would be a better way to go than `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Yes it is.  I have an extra line in the final query with a LIKE search parameter and then UNION another separate query.  I just updated it and tested it at the app level and it works great.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you should join tables using INNER or OUTER JOIN syntax. So:

```
FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
```

or perhaps you want an OUTER JOIN here?

Can you explain why you're doing a GROUP BY on wp_posts.id. Does this column not have unique values?

Comment: I was using the GROUP BY because wp_p2p when I was joining the tables, it was creating duplicate results.  Mostly because it's the only way I could think of to isolate the results.